# SVG HTML5 Video with Text Masking is blurring HTML Text outside of SVG in Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I have the following SVG that uses the `mask` element to mask over an image as well as a video but only when the video starts playing and then is stopped:

```
    <div id="svg-container">
    <svg baseProfile="tiny" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 600 300" class="svg-defs">

        <!-- Symbol with text -->
        <symbol id="s-text">
            <text id="heroText" text-anchor="middle"
                  x="50%"
                  y="50%"
                  dy=".35em"
                  class="hero-text">
                Couture Book
            </text>
        </symbol>

        <!-- Mask with text -->
        <mask id="m-text"
              maskunits="userSpaceOnUse"
              maskcontentunits="userSpaceOnUse">

            <rect
                width="100%"
                height="100%"
                class="mask__shape">
            </rect>
            <use xlink:href="#s-text"
                 class="mask__text">
            </use>

        </mask>
    </svg>

    <div class="box-with-text">

        <!-- Container for video -->
        <div id="text-fill-container" class="text-fill-container">
            <img class="text-fill-image" src="/Content/images/home/hero/hero-logo-text-fill.png" />
            <video id="heroVideo" class="text-fill-video hidden" preload="none">
                <source src="/Content/video/behind_scenes.mp4?t=@DateTime.Now.Ticks" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>

        <!-- Visible SVG -->
        <svg baseProfile="tiny" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
             xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
             xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 600 300"
             class="svg-inverted-mask">
            <rect
                width="100%"
                height="100%"
                mask="url(#m-text)"
                class="shape--fill" />
            <use xlink:href="#s-text"
                 class="text--transparent">
            </use>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
<!--//svg-->
```

Here is a screenshot of the landing/home page before the HTML5 video starts playing:

[image]

And here is a screenshot after playing the video and then stopping 10 seconds after, though the time you stop the video does not matter:

[image]

Its a little subtle, but if you click on each image to enlarge, you can clearly see the blurriness in the second screenshot. The text, such as the words "BRAZILIAN EARTH" etc are blurry, almost like some part of my SVG is "leaking" onto the text that is not in the SVG.

I am sure this has something to do with the SVG or SVG mask height and width or viewport height and widths, but I am having trouble finding it.

I am using some jQuery to hide and show the HTML elements based on the user clicking my play button:

```
  $('#btnPlay').on('click', function () {
            //if (!(video.readyState >= video.HAVE_FUTURE_DATA))
            //    return;

            $('#btnStop').show();
            $('#text-fill-container').removeClass('text-fill-container');
            $('.svg-inverted-mask').hide();
            $('.hero-caption-container').hide('slow');
            $('.text-fill-image').addClass('hidden');
            $('.text-fill-video').removeClass('hidden');

            video.play();
        });


   $('#btnStop').on('click', function () {
            video.pause();
            videoStopUpdateUI();
        });

 function videoStopUpdateUI() {
        $('#hero').show('slow');
        $('body').removeClass();
        $('#btnStop').hide();
        $('#text-fill-container').addClass('text-fill-container');
        $('.svg-inverted-mask').show();
        $('.hero-caption-container').show('fast');
        $('#btn-side-menu-slide-left').show();
        $('#btn-back').hide();
        $('.hero-secondary').hide();
    }
```

When the page loads, a static image is displayed in the SVG, behind the text mask.

When a user starts playing the video, the video is shown and the static image is hidden, when a user stops the video, the text mask overlays the frame that the video was stopped at instead of using the static image that is used when the page loads.

In Chrome everything works fine, but in Safari 9, El Capitan, when the video is stopped, text, that is not even in the SVG is strangely blurred.

You can see this in action here:
http://beta2.cmykpress.com/

The play button towards the bottom, center and the stop button is on `X` in the right corner once the video stops playing.

Comment: Don't quite see the issue with your link on Safari 9 on El Capitan. Can you share a screenshot, annotated with the exact issue?

Comment: Hi @jcaron, I have added screenshots for you, click to enlarge, the first screenshot is before pressing the play button and the second screenshot is after pressing the play button and then stopping.